# single word or short phrase for the principle of defining any term on first use?

Tags: single-word-requests

I sometimes wanted to emphasize the importance of defining any term or acronym on its first use.

I was just wondering if there is a single-word or shorter expression of this principle (define on first use) that is well-established or recognized by native English speakers.

For example,

Keep in mind, define-on-first-use/define-on-first-occurrence is very important in writing.

*Any shorter or more idiomatic phrase for expressing this?*

Comment: Probably “coinage” of a term. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/coinage

Comment: Obviously it would be silly ***not*** to provide a definition the first time you use a ***new coinage***, but there certainly won't be many of them in any given text. So I assume what OP is actually thinking of if ***the first use of a term that might be unfamiliar to the reader***. The problem being - *how to decide which terms the reader might not know*. Personally, I think electronic text-handling (HTML markup links, copy & Internet search,...) have largely eliminated the need for explicit "inline definitions" anyway, so if this concept was ever useful, it's becoming much less so now.